# What does ubuntu install dvd/cd do?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I just wonder what is going under the hood of Ubuntu installation cd/dvd process. I understand that installer has to create or format partitions, install bootloader - but what next? Does it only copy all files from cd? Or is it somehow "installed" by apt-get? How to explore this process in more detail?

Comment: This is what happens from a graphical view: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bZ4yQIVgGaUGSYu3qiUHnQt3ieBZoqunP_DcleHCr3I/preview (not what is asked here but still an interesting read). And files are copied from disk yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above remark referring to the graphical description is good, from a descriptive point of view. A technical in depth of what happens during installation is given here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/installation-guide/amd64/apds04.html, although it is given in Ubuntu commands.

Comment: Yes, this is good, very detailed! Primary, I was interested in way the software is installed and it looks like everything is installed from .deb package. Some packages are installed during the deboostrap process and more later via aptitude/apt-get. Very informative.